# Disabling works in IE8 and not in lower versions of IE

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

I have a jsp code like this

```
<html:option value="${apealstaList.appealStatusMasterId}" disabled="true">${apealstaList.appealStatusDescription}</html:option>
```

This disable the options and it works fine in IE8 and not working in the lower versions like IE7 and IE6. Please help me in this issue.

**EDIT**

Please share If there are any other alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is a known bug](http://www.gtalbot.org/BrowserBugsSection/MSIE7Bugs/OptionDisabledSupport.html).

Comment: Is there any alternate solution

Comment: You could completely remove the `<option>` tag.

Comment: You could use a custom dropdown list in Javascript.

Comment: Actually am new to this and could you just help me out in creating javascript for the above said issue. Thanks